# How do I properly map a dictionary in C# NEST?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have a field called 'GrossSalaryElements' which is a dictionary of string and decimal.

When creating an index for elastic with Nest.Object and automap on, it creates a property for each key, obviously I do not want this. I have read online that I should be using the nested data attribute, but this needs to be setup manually when creating the index. However I still seem to be running into the same issue, here is my current code, am I doing it correctly?:

```
            ElasticClient.Indices.Create(indexNameWithTenantId,
                c => c.InitializeUsing(new IndexState { Settings = new IndexSettings() }).Map<MainTermsDataModel>(
                    m=>m.AutoMap()
                    .Properties(p=>p
                        .Nested<IDictionary<string, decimal>>(x=>x
                            .Name(x=>x.GrossSalaryElements)
                            .Properties(pp=>pp
                                .Number(nn=>nn
                                    .Name(x=>x.Values)
                                    .Type(NumberType.Double)
                                )
                                .Keyword(k=>k
                                    .Name(x=>x.Keys)
                                )
                            )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution for my ask after spending few weeks on this.

To map a dictionary in C# NEST, one should map each dictionary field individually. Please refer below code snippet for reference:

```
                            foreach(var x in dictFields)
                            {
                                p = p.Object<IDictionary<string, decimal>>(Q => Q
                                .Name(char.ToLower(x[0]) + x.Substring(1))
                                .Properties(pp => pp
                                    .Number(nn => nn
                                        .Name("values")
                                        .Type(NumberType.Double)
                                    )
                                    .Keyword(k => k
                                        .Name("key")
                                    )
                                ).Dynamic(false)
                                );
                            }
```

***Please Note***: Nested data type will reduce the performance of searching and refreshing your index and hence it is not advised to go with. If the requirement contains large models with multiple objects, I recommend not to use "ElasticSearch".